# Multiple output text value setting in watson conversation

Tags: node.js, ibm-watson, watson, watson-conversation

I have following node in the conversation. I want to raise the action and based on that need to call the API. In success scenario, will show the output.text[0] and error scenario getting from output.text[1]

```
{
   "output": {
     "text": {
       "values": [
         "I want to get this with success scenario",
         "I want to get this with error scenario"
       ],
       "selection_policy": "sequential"
     },
     "action": "MyAction"
   }
 }
```

But when I am accessing this conversation node in node.js, it will always give 1st value, i.e. 'I want to get this with success scenario' It will never give output like 'I want to get this with error scenario' .

How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really complicated to answer because depends your Business role inside your Chatbot.

But, if you wanna answer one message according to the Condition...

You can see in your output the `selection_policy` is `sequential`, in the other words, first will show the 1st phrase, and just if the condition access again by the user, will show the second message.

"The order in which values in the array are returned depends on the attribute `selection_policy`."

**The better form to solve this is to create two conditions inside the Node flow for each phrase.**

For example first condition flow:

```
if bot recognizes successScenario response "I want to get this with success scenario"
```

In another second condition flow:

```
if bot recognizes errorScenario response "I want to get this with error scenario"
```

And your app with Nodejs will get the value according the condition.

See the official documentation about this [here](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-build.html#dialog-build), search about `selection_policy`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and URL(it was added 2 days ago). That links gives proper resolution. I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved that issue with the following way.

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        {
          "successMsg": "success Message",
          "errorMsg": "error message"
        }
      ]
    },
    "action": "MyAction"
  }
}
```

Reason for not going for new node, because with this action, I need to create the API and based on the API call success and fail display this message to the user. Then it will help to save one roundtrip because no need to send results status again to conversation service, it will identify the what to present to user based on the this node itself.